# Look through nether portal (gl nether mod)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, mod-identification

I watched this video: [Etho Plays Minecraft - Episode 200: 200th Special](https://youtu.be/Ut69ytsXZKM?t=1380).

At about 23 minutes, he mentions a mod called something like "gl nether mod". This mod looks really cool, but I can't find it anywhere. Has it been removed? Or moved to another mod? Or is the mod just too old, and no longer updated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a trick he did, he's simply hollowed out the area behind the portal and filled it with netherrack.

If you watch the entirety of the clip you see a creeper spawn in the area, as it is still part of the overworld.

Comment: I must have missed the creeper.  I was pretty sure he was trolling at the time.  This just confirms it.

Comment: Oh man... That would be an awesome mod!

Comment: haha, This is actually a setup that I have done a few times. Its a neat effect.. Nice to know Etho is trolling for his Specials though :D

Comment: @James He actually did it in one of his early episodes, he just used part of the episode in his special.

Answer (score -1):

I have come to the rescue it is known as the better portals mod, even though he didn’t use it in the video it is an actual mod.

https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/betterportals

Comment: Do you have a link for said mod to help the OP find it?

Comment: https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/betterportals